# Recent Intel hardware has a feature which prevents installing Ubuntu. What do do?

Tags: intel, rst

Recently I received a Dell Precision T5550 'workstation laptop' with Windows 10 preloaded.  I attempted to install Ubuntu 20 on it.  At about the 7th step or so, the install procedure stopped and told me I had to deal with 'RST', which is apparently a feature which allows, indeed, requires the operating system to interact with the firmware and access to memory.  There is a page with a 'solution' which runs for a couple of pages and involves altering the Windows registry in different ways for different machines and seems to require considerable knowledge of Windows 10, which I do not possess or want to possess.  Given a lot of time for research and experimentation, I might be able to patch Ubuntu to get around the problem, but some contributors to some web sites assert that that will impair the machine's access to its memory.  Is anyone working on this?  It seems like a major defect.  It certainly is a case of Ubuntu failing to 'just work' as it used to.

Comment: just disable it in the BIOS. See also [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/index.html), which covers the leave it on with windows option.

Comment: Depending what you want to do with Windows data, can just disable RST and reinstall windows and Ubuntu after backing up data or can change Windows to work without RST(more work).  If don't want Windows, have read that Ubuntu will work with RST as a single boot option(no Windows).  Just changing RST to ACHI in bios will make Windows not work, unless Windows is prepared first.

Comment: Have a similar laptop that came has yours with RST enabled.  Do not find any impairment, but also do not push laptop.  For day to day stuff it works well.

Comment: -- I was unable to find a setting to turn off RST in the BIOS.  Maybe it is missing from my particular machine, or maybe I missed it.  It was OK with me if Windows was cleaned completely off the machine forever, that was the original idea, but some of the commentary on the Net suggested that bad things would result.  Some of the solutions required altering the registry, others warned that a mistake might brick the machine.  I have been able to avoid Windows for the last 20 years and hope to continue in the blassed state.